# Help me to find a solution for twisted stairs corner

Tags: stairs

We are renovating our place and our floors and stairs have just done but I don’t like how our stairs turned out. It’s twisted stairs. We thinking to demo and re do again with panel going through it but I like exposed look. Is there any other solution not to demo but fix the edges? [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8CPv.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8CPv.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyUNZ.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: That configuration is only allowed in existing construction that was built that way (grandfathered.) Under any normal building code today those stairs are (rightly) considered excessively hazardous (and they are, I've used some in grandfathered buildings, and it's very easy to fall if you get to close to that edge.)

Comment: You could fill in the gaps with spackle compound other similar compatible material. Let it dry then sand until flat and even. A second attempt may be required depending on your skill set.

Comment: Which defects do you want to fix?  I see wallboard extending too far, but I also see risers extending well past the next step, which looks like poor dimensioning of a couple treads and/or risers.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it is grandfathered in, so we’re stuck with this layout. We plan on having our contractor demo the LVT and nosing back to the plywood. Well install a stringer so that it’s a straight cut for the treads / risers. In lieu of nosing, we are trying to find a minimalist type of schluter / metal trim that can keep it looking clean. Does anyone have recommendations for a nice trim where riser meets tread?

Comment: Where is the handrail for this side? Even if it is an old set of stairs, there still should be a handrail visible in this pic.  Like WillK suggested, a newel post would give a great spot to terminate all these risers, and support the handrail at the transition.

Answer (score 4):

**Cover it up with a post**

It does not look good with all those edges showing but it does look solid.  Leave it be.  Get a post that same color wood and put it in the center.  It will leave it solid and a center post might be good to grab anyway.

Cut away the part of the post towards the stairs to fit those uneven pieces into the post.   Someone there seems to be good at that kind of work.

Comment: Or, remove the trim and cut the treads & nosing to die into the post. Would make fitting the post _much_ easier that trying to fit the post around all those random edges.

Comment: @Freeman - yes yes.  You could just shave them down without concern for aesthetics and cover the new even edge with the post.